# How do I reference a range 1 column to the right of a work range using a range variable?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to work on a range of cells that changes every day. I have decided that the best way to handle this might be to use an InputBox to get the range to work on. The macro massages the data and places it 1 column to the right of the range from the InputBox, but the data is not in adjacent cells (if that makes a difference.)

I would like to select the cells 1 column to the right of the selected range where the new data is located (this is the preferred solution) and format the new data.  Or if I can't select the range, I could just select the entire column and then change the format of the entire column.

I can't figure out how to extract the range info to do the necessary math on it and then use it to change the format of the newly created data.

I have included a simplified sample of the problem area of the code.

I would appreciate your help with this.

---

```
Sub InputBox_Range_Test()    
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Application.InputBox(Prompt:=PromptString, Type:=8)

    Debug.Print rng.Address

    '
    '*** Needs to select the range that is 
    '*** 1 column to the right of the input range
    '
    Columns(rng).Select 
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00%"
    Range("I4").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out.  I was thinking about it the wrong way.  I was trying to make it harder that it needed to be.  I just had to use the offset property.

Here's what I came up with:

---

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

```
Dim rngTarget As Range

Set rngTarget = Application.InputBox(strPrompt, "Select the Range to work with", Type:=8)

Range(rngTarget.Address).Offset(, 1).Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00%"
Range("P2").Select
```

End Sub